# Lua and Visual C++

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, lua

I have a simple question. When I open VC++, create an "Empty Project," insert the Lua 5.2.0 source code, then compile, I get no errors. However, when I do this except select "Windows Forms Application" at the beginning, I get a whole bunch of errors. What may be causing this?

EDIT:

The errors are about safe versions of certain functions:

`1>..\lua-5.2.0\src\lua.c(102): error C3861: 'signal': identifier not found
1>..\lua-5.2.0\src\lua.c(178): error C3861: 'signal': identifier not found
1>..\lua-5.2.0\src\lua.c(180): error C3861: 'signal': identifier not found
1>  luac.c
1>..\lua-5.2.0\src\luac.c(43): warning C4996: 'strerror': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strerror_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string.h(157) : see declaration of 'strerror'
1>..\lua-5.2.0\src\luac.c(178): warning C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\stdio.h(234) : see declaration of 'fopen'
1>  lundump.c
1>  lvm.c
1>..\lua-5.2.0\src\lvm.c(53): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\stdio.h(371) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
1>  lzio.c
1>  Generating Code...`

Comment: "What may be causing this? " I don't know; you didn't bother to tell us what the errors *are*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because when you create a windows form application, it is actually using managed c++ (uses .net), which I don't think lua is compatible with. Take a look at http://luaplus.org/ that might be what you're looking for. It seems like it's lua for ANY .net language (which managed c++ is)